# Integrating Tableau and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Been trying to look up integrating Tableau reports into a asp.net application and can't find anything definitive.

Does anyone here have any experience integrating tableau with a web application such as ASP.Net? It'll eventually be hosted in IIS so does that make it a requirement to be ASP.Net, or can I host a traditional HTML/CSS/JS in IIS?

Comment: A quick google search brought this up - https://tableauandbehold.com/2015/06/11/embedding-tableau-server-views-in-a-c-application-part-1/ and this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26103261/showing-tableau-data-in-mvc

Comment: To add to the above content, you can use the Tableau Javascript API to integrate Tableau report on your own application. Here is the link to the current documentation - https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm